# sending notification from firebase cloud functions getting null as notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

When I am sending notifications from firebase cloud functions when the child is added to firebase database it successfully sends a notification but when I delete the child from firebase database I get the notification as a null message below is the screenshot link what I get a notification when I delete the child from firebase database

[image]

```
//import firebase functions modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listens for new debate created
exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref('app_title').onWrite(( change,context) => {
    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

       const app_title = change.after.val();

        const payload = {notification: {
            title: 'New Notification',
            body: `${app_title}`
            }
        };

   return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("appGlobal",payload)
       .then(function(response){
            console.log('Notification sent successfully:',response);
       })
       .catch(function(error){
            console.log('Notification sent failed:',error);
       });
});
```

Comment: Print your notification in logs what you get from FCM

Answer (score 2):

`change.after.val()` is null because it is deleted, you should return `change.before.val()` for deleting operaion (Ref [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45101183/7765316))

Check change like that for detecting delete

```
//Comment created

if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
    return //TODO
    });

    //Comment deleted
} else if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    return //TODO              
    });

    //Comment updated
}  else if (change.after.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
        return //TODO
    }
```

Instead of onWrite, you need to implement [onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onCreate), [onDelete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onDelete) for better results

> onWrite(), which triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in
>   the Realtime Database.
>
> onCreate(), which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime
>   Database.
>
> onUpdate(), which triggers when data is updated in the Realtime
>   Database.
>
> onDelete(), which triggers when data is deleted from the Realtime
>   Database. [(ref)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Comment: If it's works, please accept it as the answer.it helps to others too.  You are always welcome

Comment: Thank you @majuran this really helped me